# Python 3.5 Downgraded by conda when I try to install NUMPY 1.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, anaconda

This is getting really frustrating. Whenever I try to install Numpy on the prompt, Python will be downgraded to 2.7 and I can't do anything about it.

Here's the ss:
[image]

I need a Python 3.5, Numpy 1.10 and scikit-learn 0.17 but I don't know how. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean "downgraded to 2.7"? What's your Python path? Try `which python` and see the results.

Answer (score 1):

> Python 3.5, Numpy 1.10 and scikit-learn 0.17

Those versions are on the old side.
I imagine you are trying to get as close as possible to the environment used by the author of some tutorial that was written a while ago.
A fresh install might give you 1.16 and 0.20.

The conda solver was having trouble finding a compatible set of package versions using your python 3.5, which apparently led it to rewind back in time to a fairly early set of versions.
I recommend relaxing the constraint, from "equal" to "greater-or-equal":

```
conda install numpy>=1.10
```

If you get a somewhat more recent version, the tutorial likely will still work fine.

If you want to use multiple constraints, you may find it convenient to put them in an `environment.yml` file, and use `conda env update`:

```
name: tutorial
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python >= 3.5
  - numpy >= 1.10
  - scikit-learn >= 0.17
```

Remember to use `conda activate tutorial` so your `PATH` will use that environment.
For example, `$ which python` will show the newly installed interpreter, and `$ python -c 'import pprint, sys; pprint.pprint(sys.path)'` will mention a directory containing the new numpy library plus a bunch of transitive deps.